# Is there an analog to ArcGIS' "Neighborhood Toolset > Point Statistics" for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, heat-map

Is it possible to create a raster with QGIS in which the raster cell value is assigned by summing the number of vector points that are within a certain radial distance of the cell?

After much web searching, I can't seem to find it if it exists.

As far as I can tell, ArcGIS has this exact function (correct me if I'm wrong- I've never used it) in its Neighborhood Toolset called "Point Statistics."

Its [help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000qv000000.htm) will probably explain it far better than I can:

Comment: I am coding a plugin for the processing toolbox right now which among others includes a functions to do exactly what you want. Just wait a few more days/weeks ;)

Comment: Thanks Curlew- I just edited my question to be much simpler, and I think I was making the edits as you responded.  I'm looking forward to seeing your plugin- how will one access it once you're finished?

Comment: It will be a normal qgis plugin. In the meantime try to look for another way such as "rasterize points -> calculate neighborhood sums with r.neighbors and sum". Search for it.